# Excel formula to extract text substring

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to attach a relatively small Excel spreadsheet and the textbox it contains asking my questions? My questions are simple but just detailed enough that it's impossible to ask someone to give the advice I need without his/her seeing the spreadsheet. Any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

George

Comment: upload screencaps to http://imgur.com and link to them

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to achieve? If you are trying to paste the excel input into a different platform (for instance a word document). You can use paste embedded option.

1. Copy the excel reference you want
2. Go to your desired platform (ie:word)
3. Typer CNTRL + V on your keyboard
4. Select paste embed that looks as follows (in yellow)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdvIv.png)